# Configure p2 Repository Managers to connect to HTTPS repository(-ies) with client certificate(s) programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, p2

I'd like to configure p2 repository managers to connect to HTTPS repositories (Apache + client certificates).

There are several methods available to load repositories:

```
public IMetadataRepository loadRepository(URI location, IProgressMonitor monitor) throws ProvisionException, OperationCanceledException;
public IMetadataRepository loadRepository(URI location, int flags, IProgressMonitor monitor) throws ProvisionException, OperationCanceledException;
public IArtifactRepository loadRepository(URI location, IProgressMonitor monitor) throws ProvisionException;
public IArtifactRepository loadRepository(URI location, int flags, IProgressMonitor monitor) throws ProvisionException;
```

with `location` parameter I can provide URI to HTTPS server. How can I provide paths to key-stores/trust-stores that contain client and CA certificates? I don't like to use global key-stores for Java process.

Comment: This method of adding the repositories programmatically - did it work? Can you please post your full `P2Util` class? (or whereever you're doing the loading of repos and checking for updates). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution. p2 uses [ECF](http://www.eclipse.org/ecf/) as communication layer.

To activate SSL support:

- install and start bundle(s): `org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient.ssl` and/or `org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.ssl`
- create SSLSocketFactory object with keystore(s) and register as OSGi service

  > SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
  >
  > sslContext.init(keymanagers, trustmanagers, null);
  >
  > SSLSocketFactory factory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
  >
  > bundleContext.registerService(SSLSocketFactory.class.getName(),
  >   factory, null);

Answer (score 0):

See "Secure storage runtime options" help chapter: http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-securestorage-options.htm

...and also http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html

```
-eclipse.keyring <file path> (Equinox)
    Set to override location of the default secure storage
```

Probably you can set this value somehow programmatically, have a look in the sources.

Comment: These settings are for the whole Eclipse Java process. I'd like to provide storage on-the-fly, because it's a part of my config bundle.